# javascript multiple filter or condtional code optimization

Tags: javascript, performance, lodash

I have an array of object like this :

```
const items = [
   {
       id: 1,
       status: "active",
       paid: true,
       name: "item-1"
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       status: "active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-2"
   },
   {
       id: 3,
       status: "not active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-3"
   },
]
```

and i have a function to filter it like this :

```
// arr is array of items
// status if null mean select all by status
// paid if null mean select all by paid
// status and paid if null mean select all by status and paid
function filterItem(arr, status, paid){
    const result = [];
    arr.forEach((item) => {
         if (status && paid) {
                if (status === item.status
                     && paid === item.paid.toString()) {
                     result.push(item);
                }
         } 
         else if(status){
                 if (status === item.status) {
                      result.push(item);
                 }
         }
         else if(paid){
                 if (paid == item.paid.toString()) {
                       result.push(item);
                 }
         }
         else result.push(item);
    })
    return result;
}
```

in this function **filterItem** :

**status** is string and may null

**paid** is string and may null

expected output :

**if status and paid is null** `console.log(filterItem(items, null, null));`

```
[
   {
       id: 1,
       status: "active",
       paid: true,
       name: "item-1"
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       status: "active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-2"
   },
   {
       id: 3,
       status: "not active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-3"
   },
]
```

**if paid null and status active** `console.log(filterItem(items, 'active', null))`

```
[
   {
       id: 1,
       status: "active",
       paid: true,
       name: "item-1"
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       status: "active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-2"
   }
]
```

and etc

I believe there is a short way, using es6 or lodash. I need your suggestion please review my simple code and is there a more simple code than mine?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: seems no match would be a better approach to filter as in most match cases you are pushing the item in result and also check [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: How about keeping a snippet like the one I made for you

Comment: This question might get a better chance at codereview - but look at `filter` which is so prominent in your question

Comment: @AZ_ i tried using filter, but when null, it will match with null, in my code, have othe condition

Comment: @mplungjan okay i will try codereview,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
const items=[{id:1,status:"active",paid:true,name:"item-1"},{id:2,status:"active",paid:false,name:"item-2"},{id:3,status:"not active",paid:false,name:"item-3"},]

function filterItem(arr, status, paid){
  return arr.filter(a =>
    (status === null || a.status === status) &&
    (paid === null || a.paid === paid)
  )
}

console.log(filterItem(items, "active", null))
console.log(filterItem(items, null, false))
console.log(filterItem(items, "active", true)) // both conditions
console.log(filterItem(items, null, null)) // returns everything
```

Comment: thanks, simpler and easy to understand

Comment: this approach goes longer and longer for every new added property. but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic approach and build first an array with the wanted filters/properties/values and then filter the array by using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with the filters.

This approach is easily extensible for more properties, if wanted.

```js
function filterItem(array, status, paid) {
    var filters = [];

    if (status !== null) filters.push(['status', status]);
    if (paid !== null) filters.push(['paid', paid]);

    return array.filter(item => filters.every(([k, v]) => item[k] === v));
}

const items = [{ id: 1, status: "active", paid: true, name: "item-1" }, { id: 2, status: "active", paid: false, name: "item-2" }, { id: 3, status: "not active", paid: false, name: "item-3" }];

console.log(filterItem(items, "active", true));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pass an Object reference of your desired filter-criteria and using `.every()` you can check that all criteria given to the Function matches the items in the Array. This way you're not limited to the `status` or `paid` properties, you can check for any property that may exist in the Object Array.

```js
const items = [
   {
       id: 1,
       status: "active",
       paid: true,
       name: "item-1"
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       status: "active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-2"
   },
   {
       id: 3,
       status: "not active",
       paid: false,
       name: "item-3"
   },
]

const filter = (array, criteria) => {
  const criteriaKeys = Object.keys(criteria)
  
  return array.filter(item => criteriaKeys.every(k => item[k] === criteria[k]))
}

console.log(filter(items, { status: 'active', paid: true }))
console.log(filter(items, { status: 'not active', paid: false }))
console.log(filter(items, { status: 'not active', paid: true }))
console.log(filter(items, { status: 'active' }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should be little bit more effective and still readable:

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        status: "active",
        paid: true,
        name: "item-1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        status: "active",
        paid: false,
        name: "item-2"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        status: "not active",
        paid: false,
        name: "item-3"
    },
 ];

 let filterFunction = (ar, paid, status)=>{
  return ar.filter(item=>{
   let res = true;
   if(paid){
    res = item.paid === paid;
   }
   if(status){
    res = item.status === status;
   }
   return res;
  });
 };

 console.log(filterFunction(items, null, "active"));
```